# Angular2 app not showing loading text on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs

I have an angular2 app with typescript that uses SystemJS; I used the following [seed app](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed).

When on desktop, you can see the loading text in between the tags (e.g. `Loading...`).

On my index page, I have a small loading `div` to show my apps being slow on first-time load.

But this `div` doesn't ever show on mobile.

**Index Code**

```
<app>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">                 
                  <div class="navbar-header">      
                    <a class="navbar-brand col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                      <img src="./assets/logo.png" />
                    </a>
                  </div> 
            </div> 
         </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="bounceInDown animated">  
        <div class="loading-wrapper animated fadeIn">      
            <p class="loading-text">Hold on!<br />We're unpacking...</p>
            <div class="loading-icon preload"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</app>
```

Let me know if you need any more code examples.

I basically want this `div` inside the `app` tags to show on mobile; I'm open to any jQuery mobile tricks, too.

It seems to be the `keyframe`. Can you let me know whats wrong?

**CSS and keyframe Code**

```
 .loading-icon {
        animation: scaleout 1.0s infinite ease-in-out;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        -webkit-animation: scaleout 1.0s infinite ease-in-out;
        width: 40px;
    }
} 

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleout {
  0% { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  } 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: try <app><div style="height: 100px; width:100px; background-color:red;"></div></app> ... I suspect loading of animation is taking time

Comment: its only css animation. it works fine on desktop but on mobile you cant see it

Comment: Please show us the real working page

Comment: I see bubble in the centre

Comment: Yeh thats because your looking at desktop? it works fine on desktop

Comment: HTC mobile? hmm I have iphone 6 plus and I dont see it

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what the problem is here. Basically it seems that you have a static page that doesn't work correctly on mobile. Can you make a plunkr or something to help illustrate the problem?

Comment: Try to add something to your index.html page to avoid the white page effect, the issue here seems to be that your app needs to be loaded to show your custom loader.

Answer (score 3):

Safari is picky on keyframe animations, if nothing is showing try removing the bounceInDown class and then try to re-add the animation features one by one and see what breaks.

EDIT: first try to move the bounceInDown -class in your css to before the 
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown

Comment: I've added my keyframe code above. it seems to be my key frame causing trouble.

Comment: that css works in safari on mac and iphone.

is it just the dot that is not showing for you on mobile? I cant see the "unpacking.." text even, and that has a different keyframe animation

Comment: On my iphone in safari I just get white screen. but when i take keyframe out it works fine. seems to be something wrong with my keyframe code above?

Comment: in `@keyframes scaleout {}` you don't need the webkit stuff, you have that in `@-webkit-keyframes scaleout`

should not matter, but safari is picky

Comment: I've narrowed it down and on a safari iphone i just keep getting a white background on load rather than the loading text. Does angular2 work different on mobile when loading?

Comment: you might be able to debug it using safari on a mac connected to the phone via usb or on a PC maybe vscode
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/08/22/introducing-ios-web-debugging-for-vs-code-on-windows-and-mac.

also, in the pasted css in your question there is an extra } after the .loading-icon{}

Comment: The additional } was just me pasting it in.

Comment: It seems to be same on chrome on my iPhone. White screen until app loads

Comment: "Does angular2 work different on mobile when loading?"  ... no, and in this case it does not matter. the content inside the app-tags is replaced when angular starts, so the problem is probably the same on a static page

Comment: Doesn't seem like I can do anything then?

Comment: Even if I remove all animation and css and just have loading text. It doesnt show on mobile apply devices. You just get white screen and then it shows the website when its ready